# Firebird: table and null data

Tags: null, firebird

I'm working with Firebird database. I have a big table with many thousand of rows. Each line records the status of an object at regular intervals for many objects. I need to register new properties for one object only.
I think I have 2 possibilities:

1. add the new columns to the table even if I have a lot of null values
2. create a table with the only properties that interest me and bind it appropriately to the first

which solution is the best for not having a loss of performance?

Comment: The only way to be 100% sure is to test and measure. In any case, are you talking about performance implications of adding the column, or of using the column?

Comment: Adding the column. In particular I'm interested to not increasing the size of all' database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a new column to a table will not modify existing data. Records in the database are versioned with a so-called format version at the time the record was written. This format version describes the columns (and other column related metadata).

If you alter a table to add a column, then a new format version is added. When reading records, Firebird will read the row using the original format version, and then - in memory - 'upgrade' the row to the latest format version, eg adding new columns with a null value (or the default value), removing columns that have been dropped, or changing sizes, etc.

In other words, adding columns is cheap. There is one exception: since Firebird 3, adding a column with a `NOT NULL`-constraint if there are existing records will require a default value, otherwise the addition fails. In earlier versions this would silently add a `NOT NULL` column containing `NULL` for existing records, leaving fixing of the data for those rows to the database owner.

Regarding storage itself, Firebird uses a simple form of RLE compression to compress records on disk. Null values written using the new format version do take up some space because of this, but max 2 bytes for most types, and multiples of 2 bytes for column types longer than 127 bytes. As an extreme form of optimization, it might make sense to group columns that are usually `NULL` together (but the performance benefit is likely very small).

Regarding runtime performance, since Firebird 3 (and assuming a client that supports wire protocol 13 or higher), columns that are `NULL` are skipped in the wire protocol (meaning that no data is sent for that column), which reduce the number of bytes sent over the network.